How to centralize vertcally and horizontally a CSS Grid


body {
  background-color: hsl(210, 46%, 95%);
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: "Barlow Semi Condensed", sans-serif;
  height: 100vh;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  justify-self: right;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.attribution {
  font-size: 11px;
  text-align: center;
}
.attribution a {
  color: hsl(228, 45%, 44%);
}

.testimonialsmain {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  gap: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.testimonialitem {
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.testimonialitem:nth-child(3) {
  grid-row: span 2;
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  padding: 20px;
  display: grid;
}

.testimonialitem:nth-child(1) {
  grid-column: span 2;
  background-color: hsl(263, 55%, 52%);
  color: hsl(0, 0%, 81%);
  padding: 20px;
  display: grid;

  width: auto;
}

.testimonialitem:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: hsl(217, 19%, 35%);
  color: hsl(0, 0%, 81%);
  padding: 20px;
  display: grid;

  width: auto;
}

.testimonialitem:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  padding: 20px;
  display: grid;

  width: auto;
}
.testimonialitem:nth-child(5) {
  grid-column: span 2;
  background-color: hsl(219, 29%, 14%);
  color: hsl(0, 0%, 81%);
  padding: 20px;
  display: grid;

  width: auto;
}

.card {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 6fr;
}

.pic {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.intro {
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-size: large;
  z-index: 2;
}

.testimonial {
  padding-top: 10px;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

    <link
      rel="icon"
      type="image/png"
      sizes="32x32"
      href="./images/favicon-32x32.png"
    />

    <title>Frontend Mentor | Testimonials Grid</title>

    <!-- Feel free to remove these styles or customise in your own stylesheet  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Barlow+Semi+Condensed:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="main">
      <div class="testimonialsmain">
        <div class="testimonialitem">
          <svg width="104" height="102" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path
              d="M104 102V59.727H84.114c0-5.871.689-11.182 2.068-15.933 1.379-4.75 3.42-9.287 6.125-13.61C95.01 25.86 98.909 22.257 104 19.375V0c-9.758 4.27-17.712 9.874-23.864 16.813-6.151 6.939-10.712 14.545-13.681 22.818C63.485 47.904 62 59.941 62 75.74V102h42zm-62 0V59.727H22.114c0-5.871.689-11.182 2.068-15.933 1.379-4.75 3.42-9.287 6.125-13.61C33.01 25.86 36.909 22.257 42 19.375V0c-9.652 4.27-17.58 9.874-23.784 16.813C12.01 23.752 7.424 31.358 4.455 39.631 1.485 47.904 0 59.941 0 75.74V102h42z"
              fill="#A775F1"
              fill-rule="nonzero"
            />
          </svg>
          <div class="card">
            <img src="./images/image-daniel.jpg" class="pic" />
            Daniel Clifford <br />
            Verified Graduate
          </div>

          <div class="intro">
            I received a job offer mid-course, and the subjects I learned were
            current, if not more so, in the company I joined. I honestly feel I
            got every penny’s worth.
          </div>
          <div class="testimonial">
            “ I was an EMT for many years before I joined the bootcamp. I’ve
            been looking to make a transition and have heard some people who had
            an amazing experience here. I signed up for the free intro course
            and found it incredibly fun! I enrolled shortly thereafter. The next
            12 weeks was the best - and most grueling - time of my life. Since
            completing the course, I’ve successfully switched careers, working
            as a Software Engineer at a VR startup. ”
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="testimonialitem">
          <div class="card">
            <img src="./images/image-jonathan.jpg" class="pic" /> Jonathan
            Walters <br />
            Verified Graduate
          </div>

          <div class="intro">
            The team was very supportive and kept me motivated
          </div>
          <div class="testimonial">
            “ I started as a total newbie with virtually no coding skills. I now
            work as a mobile engineer for a big company. This was one of the
            best investments I’ve made in myself. ”
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="testimonialitem">
          <div class="card">
            <img src="./images/image-kira.jpg" class="pic" /> Kira Whittle
            <br />
            Verified Graduate
          </div>
          <div class="intro">
            Such a life-changing experience. Highly recommended!
          </div>
          <div class="testimonial">
            “ Before joining the bootcamp, I’ve never written a line of code. I
            needed some structure from professionals who can help me learn
            programming step by step. I was encouraged to enroll by a former
            student of theirs who can only say wonderful things about the
            program. The entire curriculum and staff did not disappoint. They
            were very hands-on and I never had to wait long for assistance. The
            agile team project, in particular, was outstanding. It took my
            learning to the next level in a way that no tutorial could ever
            have. In fact, I’ve often referred to it during interviews as an
            example of my developent experience. It certainly helped me land a
            job as a full-stack developer after receiving multiple offers. 100%
            recommend! ”
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="testimonialitem">
          <div class="card">
            <img src="./images/image-jeanette.jpg" class="pic" /> Jeanette
            Harmon <br />
            Verified Graduate
          </div>
          <div class="intro">An overall wonderful and rewarding experience</div>
          <div class="testimonial">
            “ Thank you for the wonderful experience! I now have a job I really
            enjoy, and make a good living while doing something I love. ”
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="testimonialitem">
          <div class="card">
            <img src="./images/image-patrick.jpg" class="pic" /> Patrick Abrams
            <br />
            Verified Graduate
          </div>
          <div class="intro">
            Awesome teaching support from TAs who did the bootcamp themselves.
            Getting guidance from them and learning from their experiences was
            easy.
          </div>
          <div class="testimonial">
            “ The staff seem genuinely concerned about my progress which I find
            really refreshing. The program gave me the confidence necessary to
            be able to go out in the world and present myself as a capable
            junior developer. The standard is above the rest. You will get the
            personal attention you need from an incredible community of smart
            and amazing people. ”
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="attribution">
        Challenge by
        <a href="https://www.frontendmentor.io?ref=challenge" target="_blank"
          >Frontend Mentor</a
        >. Coded by <a href="#">Aparna Gopalakrishnan</a>.
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>



I have created a Grid with 3 columns and 2 rows. But not able to centralize it vertically and horizontally.
Can someone please suggest a solution that will work with the code that I have written?
I tried using different properties like align-items, align-self, align-content etc. Also refered to some of the solutions in this forum. Nothing worked for me so far.
padding is working. But with my basic knowledge, my understanding is that it is not a good design for a responsive page.
Now the Grid is located at the top of the page.The expected result is to move it down to the middle of the page as in the below screen shot.


Please provide a code snippet instead  of a link to your github repo. Links may get down for whatever reason and this post would not be relevant anymore for future user (futhermore no one wants to clone a repo to help out)

I have included the code here. Please check it and let me know.

If someone can open this question, I could have added an answer on how I solved my problem

Someone reopened it

Solution
To center the content vertically and horizontally using a grid container, you need to apply your styling from the parent element of your content. Per your example, your content is within testimonialsmain, so the parent div is main. First, you need to set main to occupy the whole page like this:
.main {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

If you want to view this using mobile, you may do this:
.main {
  width: 100dvw;
  height: 100dvh;
}

After that, you can use grid container to center your content vertically and horizontally like this:
.main {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}

By default, the div will have default width of 100%, so you need to set max-width for your content like this:
.testimonialsmain {
  max-width: 1000px;
  /* other styles */
}

You can refer to this for your solution.


*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: hsl(210, 46%, 95%);
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: "Barlow Semi Condensed", sans-serif;
  height: 100vh;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  justify-self: right;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.attribution {
  font-size: 11px;
  text-align: center;
}

.attribution a {
  color: hsl(228, 45%, 44%);
}

.main {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}

.testimonialsmain {
  max-width: 1000px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  gap: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.testimonialitem {
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.testimonialitem:nth-child(3) {
  grid-row: span 2;
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  padding: 20px;
  display: grid;
}

.testimonialitem:nth-child(1) {
  grid-column: span 2;
  background-color: hsl(263, 55%, 52%);
  color: hsl(0, 0%, 81%);
  padding: 20px;
  display: grid;
  width: auto;
}

.testimonialitem:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: hsl(217, 19%, 35%);
  color: hsl(0, 0%, 81%);
  padding: 20px;
  display: grid;
  width: auto;
}

.testimonialitem:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  padding: 20px;
  display: grid;
  width: auto;
}

.testimonialitem:nth-child(5) {
  grid-column: span 2;
  background-color: hsl(219, 29%, 14%);
  color: hsl(0, 0%, 81%);
  padding: 20px;
  display: grid;
  width: auto;
}

.card {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 6fr;
}

.pic {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.intro {
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-size: large;
  z-index: 2;
}

.testimonial {
  padding-top: 10px;
}
<div class="main">
  <div class="testimonialsmain">
    <div class="testimonialitem">
      <svg width="104" height="102" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path
              d="M104 102V59.727H84.114c0-5.871.689-11.182 2.068-15.933 1.379-4.75 3.42-9.287 6.125-13.61C95.01 25.86 98.909 22.257 104 19.375V0c-9.758 4.27-17.712 9.874-23.864 16.813-6.151 6.939-10.712 14.545-13.681 22.818C63.485 47.904 62 59.941 62 75.74V102h42zm-62 0V59.727H22.114c0-5.871.689-11.182 2.068-15.933 1.379-4.75 3.42-9.287 6.125-13.61C33.01 25.86 36.909 22.257 42 19.375V0c-9.652 4.27-17.58 9.874-23.784 16.813C12.01 23.752 7.424 31.358 4.455 39.631 1.485 47.904 0 59.941 0 75.74V102h42z"
              fill="#A775F1"
              fill-rule="nonzero"
            />
          </svg>
      <div class="card">
        <img src="./images/image-daniel.jpg" class="pic" /> Daniel Clifford <br /> Verified Graduate
      </div>

      <div class="intro">
        I received a job offer mid-course, and the subjects I learned were current, if not more so, in the company I joined. I honestly feel I got every penny’s worth.
      </div>
      <div class="testimonial">
        “ I was an EMT for many years before I joined the bootcamp. I’ve been looking to make a transition and have heard some people who had an amazing experience here. I signed up for the free intro course and found it incredibly fun! I enrolled shortly thereafter.
        The next 12 weeks was the best - and most grueling - time of my life. Since completing the course, I’ve successfully switched careers, working as a Software Engineer at a VR startup. ”
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="testimonialitem">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="./images/image-jonathan.jpg" class="pic" /> Jonathan Walters <br /> Verified Graduate
      </div>

      <div class="intro">
        The team was very supportive and kept me motivated
      </div>
      <div class="testimonial">
        “ I started as a total newbie with virtually no coding skills. I now work as a mobile engineer for a big company. This was one of the best investments I’ve made in myself. ”
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="testimonialitem">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="./images/image-kira.jpg" class="pic" /> Kira Whittle
        <br /> Verified Graduate
      </div>
      <div class="intro">
        Such a life-changing experience. Highly recommended!
      </div>
      <div class="testimonial">
        “ Before joining the bootcamp, I’ve never written a line of code. I needed some structure from professionals who can help me learn programming step by step. I was encouraged to enroll by a former student of theirs who can only say wonderful things about
        the program. The entire curriculum and staff did not disappoint. They were very hands-on and I never had to wait long for assistance. The agile team project, in particular, was outstanding. It took my learning to the next level in a way that no
        tutorial could ever have. In fact, I’ve often referred to it during interviews as an example of my developent experience. It certainly helped me land a job as a full-stack developer after receiving multiple offers. 100% recommend! ”
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="testimonialitem">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="./images/image-jeanette.jpg" class="pic" /> Jeanette Harmon <br /> Verified Graduate
      </div>
      <div class="intro">An overall wonderful and rewarding experience</div>
      <div class="testimonial">
        “ Thank you for the wonderful experience! I now have a job I really enjoy, and make a good living while doing something I love. ”
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="testimonialitem">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="./images/image-patrick.jpg" class="pic" /> Patrick Abrams
        <br /> Verified Graduate
      </div>
      <div class="intro">
        Awesome teaching support from TAs who did the bootcamp themselves. Getting guidance from them and learning from their experiences was easy.
      </div>
      <div class="testimonial">
        “ The staff seem genuinely concerned about my progress which I find really refreshing. The program gave me the confidence necessary to be able to go out in the world and present myself as a capable junior developer. The standard is above the rest. You
        will get the personal attention you need from an incredible community of smart and amazing people. ”
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="attribution">
    Challenge by
    <a href="https://www.frontendmentor.io?ref=challenge" target="_blank">Frontend Mentor</a
        >. Coded by <a href="#">Aparna Gopalakrishnan</a>.
  </div>
</div>



Bonus
After you applied all the styles as I described above, you may find that you still see scroll bars both horizontally and vertically. This is due to by default, different browsers and elements have different default styles. You can use below CSS to reset it:
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


Set the align-content property and the justify-content property to the centre. Make sure there is some space horizontally and vertically, otherwise the properties won't be effective.

Sorry that my code was not added in the first submission. Can you please check the code that I added and let me know where I can add these properties suggested by you? I think I already tried it once before based on the suggestion from another post in this forum.

Add the properties to the grid container. Afterwards, adjust the margin-top so that you have a space to the top, and adjust the margin-right and left so that you have some spaces as well. This is how I modified your grid container.
`
.testimonialsmain {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
align-content: center;
justify-content: center;
margin-top: 10em;
gap: 20px;
padding: 20px;
margin-left: 150px;
margin-right: 200px;
margin-right: 200px;
}`

@StephenMutheu please add in your solution code as the example from the OP

Can you show me how to do that bro, I have been struggling with it and it's limiting me in helping, I found some 5 methods to do it, but none worked!

Wait, I was talking about "how to answer question in Stackoverflow the correct way"... Seems like you're talking about how to center the whole container... Which do you mean bro? Both also I'm willing to help
